# SSH PAC app cannot connect to upgraded system

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm running the SSH client PAC on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop. It has been working great connecting to many cloud servers. One of those servers was running Ubuntu 20.04 and I was able to log onto it with PAC. I recently did a new install of Ubuntu 22.04 on that remote server and now PAC refuses to connect to it, getting this error immediately:

```
<-= DISCONNECTED (PRESS <ENTER> TO RECONNECT) (Sun Jul 30 21:15:02 2023)
```

PAC continues to connect to all my other remote servers, and if I run a different SSH client like Remmina, or SSH from a terminal window, I can log onto the remote 22.04 system.
Is there some system key that PAC has remembered so now it refuses to connect? How can I reset PAC to give the new system another chance? I really don't want to have to use one SSH client for this system and a different SSH client for all the others.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my home folder there is a tree of files for snap and this one:

```
~/snap/pac-vs/common/ssh/known_hosts
```

is a text file with a list of all known hosts. I deleted the line that described the host I could no longer log onto, restarted PAC, and it now connects to that host again.
I assume this is a security feature to prevent you from connecting to a 'man in the middle', but they should tell you this is what is happening and give you the option to re-certify the host when you know there is a reason for the system key to change.